# How to link SQLite3 in Objective C command line tool?

Tags: objective-c, macos, sqlite, command-line-interface

I'm making a command line tool to create some database benchmarks, but I realize I have no idea how to get SQLite3 to work in this environment!

Comment: Include it or link to it?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this value `-lsqlite3.0` to Other Linker Flags in Build Settings fixed the problem.

Here's an example file I can run now.

```
#import "SQLExample.h" // Nothing important in the header
#import <sqlite3.h>

@implementation SQLExample {
    sqlite3 *_database;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)sqliteExample {
    NSString *sqLiteDb = PATH_TO_DB;
    if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
    }

    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *query = @"SELECT A, B FROM C";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
        == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *c_A = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            char *c_B = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);

            NSString *A = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:c_A];
            NSString *B = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:c_B];

            [results addObject:@[A, B]];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }

    return results;
}

@end
```

Comment: But you see, that's linking. Hence my other comment. You asked the wrong question.

Comment: @matt you're probably right. updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe consider telling future readers the other half of the equation - namely what file(s) you had to `#include` or `import` and what directory you told Xcode to look in for header files for `sqlite`. I might upvote your answer then ;-)